# Doubly linked list insert and display and search and remove

Tags: c++

I am implementing a doubly linked list and my search and remove function is giving me an error.
I am new to doubly linked list so any help would be appreciated.

this is my insert function.

```
void push(student s)
{

   if ( head == NULL)
   {
       node *tmp = new node;
       tmp->data = s;
       tmp->next = NULL;
       tmp->prev = NULL;
       head = tmp;
       tail = tmp;
   }
    else if ( head != NULL)
    {
        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = s;
        tmp->next = head;
        head->prev = tmp;
        head = tmp;
    }



}
```

this is my display function

```
void display()
{
    node *current = head;

    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data.name << endl;
        cout << current->data.GPA << endl;
        cout << current->data.id << endl;
        cout << current->data.university << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

this is my remove

```
void removeStudent(int id)
    {
    //loop through list to find id
    node *current = head;

    while ( head != NULL)
    {
        //go through all data



        //find data that matches id
        if ( current->data.id == id)
        {
            //delete the match
            node *trash;
            trash = current;
            current->prev->next = current->next;
            current->next->prev = current->prev;

            delete trash;


        }
        else{
            current = current->next;
        }

    }

}
```

this is my main

```
int main()
{

    student me;
    student you;
    you.id = 9;
    you.GPA = 9.8;
    you.name = "peter";
    you.university = "stc";
    me.id = 20;
    me.GPA = 20.0;
    me.name = "robert";
    me.university = "utpa";
    student mee;
    mee.id = 15;
    mee.GPA = 8.9;
    mee.name = "mike";
    mee.university = "utpa";
    studentList list;
    list.push(me);
    list.push(you);
    list.push(mee);
    list.pop();
    list.removeStudent(15);
    list.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear whether `push` should push at the front or the back, could you clarify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `push` function.  You can greatly simplify it to avoid your conditional logic problems:

```
void push(student s)
{
   node *tmp = new node;
   tmp->data = s;
   tmp->next = head; // this works even when head is NULL
   tmp->prev = NULL;

   if (head == NULL)
   {
       head = tmp;
       tail = tmp;
   }
   else
   {
       head->prev = tmp;
       head = tmp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Even that's a little more complicated than it needs to be -- if the `if` condition `head == NULL` fails, then `head` *must* not be NULL. IOW, there's no need to test `head != NULL`, just use `else` by itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( head == NULL)
{
   ...
   head = tmp;
}
if ( head != NULL)
{
    ...
    head = tmp;
}
```

You check if `head` is `NULL`, then if it is, assign `head`. You then check if `head` is *not* `NULL`, by which point it definitely isn't as you've assigned it above, and then do other operations.

Easy solution, change the two `if` constructs to an `if`...`else if`, e.g.

```
if ( head == NULL)
{
   ...
   head = tmp;
}
else if ( head != NULL)
{
    ...
    head = tmp;
}
```

Comment: See my comment on Zac's answer -- your second `if` is redundant.